# sqoop null pointer exception

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, sqoop

I am trying to run a sqoop import but it is failing with null pointer exception. Can somebody please help?

This is the command I ran:

```
sqoop import-all-tables --bindir ./  --num-mappers 1   --connect "jdbc:mysql://localhost/retail_db"   --username=*****   --password=******   --hive-import   --hive-overwrite   --create-hive-table   --compress   --compression-codec org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec   --outdir java_files --bindir ./sqoop/
```

And this is what I get:

```
16/08/14 12:14:47 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.6
16/08/14 12:14:47 WARN tool.BaseSqoopTool: Setting your password on the command-line is insecure. Consider using -P instead.
16/08/14 12:14:47 INFO tool.BaseSqoopTool: Using Hive-specific delimiters for output. You can override
16/08/14 12:14:47 INFO tool.BaseSqoopTool: delimiters with --fields-terminated-by, etc.
16/08/14 12:14:48 INFO manager.MySQLManager: Preparing to use a MySQL streaming resultset.
16/08/14 12:14:48 INFO tool.CodeGenTool: Beginning code generation
16/08/14 12:14:48 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM `categories` AS t LIMIT 1
16/08/14 12:14:48 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM `categories` AS t LIMIT 1
16/08/14 12:14:48 INFO orm.CompilationManager: HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME is /usr/local/hadoop
Note: ./categories.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
16/08/14 12:14:49 INFO orm.CompilationManager: Writing jar file: ./categories.jar
16/08/14 12:14:49 ERROR sqoop.Sqoop: Got exception running Sqoop: java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.<init>(Arrays.java:2842)
    at java.util.Arrays.asList(Arrays.java:2828)
    at org.apache.sqoop.util.FileListing.getFileListingNoSort(FileListing.java:76)
    at org.apache.sqoop.util.FileListing.getFileListingNoSort(FileListing.java:82)
    at org.apache.sqoop.util.FileListing.getFileListingNoSort(FileListing.java:82)
    at org.apache.sqoop.util.FileListing.getFileListingNoSort(FileListing.java:82)
    at org.apache.sqoop.util.FileListing.getFileListingNoSort(FileListing.java:82)
    at org.apache.sqoop.util.FileListing.getFileListing(FileListing.java:67)
    at com.cloudera.sqoop.util.FileListing.getFileListing(FileListing.java:39)
    at org.apache.sqoop.orm.CompilationManager.addClassFilesFromDir(CompilationManager.java:284)
    at org.apache.sqoop.orm.CompilationManager.jar(CompilationManager.java:346)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.CodeGenTool.generateORM(CodeGenTool.java:109)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:478)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportAllTablesTool.run(ImportAllTablesTool.java:111)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:143)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:179)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:218)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:227)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:236)
```

Comment: --bindir is repeated two times in your command, also do you really need a external location for it? , because it usually stores compiled objects and by default it uses tmp directory

Comment: Thanks for pointing out --bindir typo. I added --bindir to deal with class not found exception. I finally fixed it by adding value of mapreduce.framework.name as yarn in mapred-site.xml

Comment: @Uday, Can you describe more specifically ? Stuck here for 2 days,Thanks a lot!